# unable to retrieve slack messages using outgoing webhooks

Tags: java, api, postman, slack

I am new to Slack Webhooks and am trying to retrieve Slack channel messages using Outgoing Webhooks API.

Below is my get GET API.

https://slack.com/api/conversations.history?token=60ClVADXdNAlOfGr239oI8hl&channel=auto_test&limit=10&inclusive=true

API response code:

200 Ok

Below is my response Body:

{
    "ok": false,
    "error": "invalid_auth"
}

Can any one please suggest how to use Outgoing Webhook API. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your token should be "Bot User OAuth Access Token", which is present in OAuth & Permissions Tab and starting with xoxb.
Provide channelId in channel=channelId

Comment: was this helpful?

Answer (score 1):

Use "Bot User OAuth Access Token" , In "OAuth and permissions Tab" Format is 
xoxb-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx. And then add scope "channels:history" and reinstall your app in slack. And then try to get conversation history with channel id .